# Pandas: Drop a row if it contains a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe and I need to exclude some rows containing a value that is a confound for me.

I have in mind a if statement nested in a for loop like this

```
for x in range (6655):
test = pseudoF2['Match'][x]

if test[:2].lower() == 'ab':
    pseudoF2.drop(test, inplace=True)
```

the problem is that I am constantly getting a key error "not found in axis"

just to have an idea, my dataframe is something like this:

```
Word    Match   Value1  Value2
1   Ab-art  Un-ans  1.95    0.15
2   Ab-art  An-ans  1.95    0.15
3   Ab-art  Um-ans  1.90    0.10
4   Ab-art  Tu-ort  2.15    0.35
5   Ab-drift    An-klift    2.90    0.25
(...)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try adding `axis=1` in your `drop` brackets.

Comment: No, unfortunately also with axis=1 it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `regular expression` to check whether there is `ab` in `Match` column, then you can drop those `indices`

As suggested by Jezreal more elegant solution

```py
df[~df['Match'].str.contains(r'(?i)^ab')]
```

Old solution

```py
df.drop(df[df['Match'].str.contains(r'(?i)^ab')].index, inplace=True)
```